# Error while checking filesystem. Not authorized to perform operation (udisks-error-quark,3)

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, disk-check

I have been getting disk errors from an NTFS-formatted internal SATA HDD on a Lubuntu 20.04.6 LTS system. For example:
`rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/media/WD4Tb/some-file": Input/output error (5)`
(the error is from the target of the rsync command)

When I try to check the filesystem (from the Disks app) I get this error:
`Error while checking filesystem. Not authorized to perform operation (udisks-error-quark,3)`
I managed to unmount the drive, but I still get the error when I try to check the drive. I do NOT have Chrome Remote Desktop installed. My user is in the sudo group. Any ideas?

Comment: Was the NTFS volume last successfully accessed on a Windows system with "Fast Boot" enabled? That leaves partitions in a legally un-understandable state.

Comment: No - the last access was from the nightly rsync backup on the Ubuntu machine. Incidentally I can read and write to the disk fine for the most part - there are just a couple of files that cannot be copied for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you are not specify enough in your question and have not specified what you already tried, here are some proposals

try formating the drive using and also creating a new filesystem (vfat).

## mkfs.vfat /path/to/disk

this is tries changing the filesystem type after which you can use tools like disks or gparted to change filesystem type

I hope it helps you view the specificity of your question.

Comment: The drive is full of data which I want to keep, and which is only reporting errors on a couple of files, so reformatting would not be a good option for me. In terms of what I have already tried - I have only tried the Check and Repair options in the Disks app, under a user which is a member of the sudo group, Is there anything else that I should be trying?